# Faster approach extracting lower triangle of multidimensional array using Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Assume a 4D array of shape `4,4,1,1`. The objective is to extract the lower-triangle of an `(n, m)` array.

Currently, the following code which rely on a for loop, does the job.

```
import numpy as np
lw_up_pair = np.tril_indices(4, -1)
arr=np.zeros((4,4,1,1))

arr[1,:1,:,0]=1
arr[2,:2,0,0]=2
arr[3,:3,0,0]=3

ext=[arr [x, i, :, 0] for x,i in zip(lw_up_pair [0],lw_up_pair [1])] # expected output
```

However, I wonder whether there is more faster or `numpy` build-in approach that can achieve the similar result?

Comment: The zip is `np.stack(lw_up_pair, -1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
rows, cols = lw_up_pair
ext = arr[rows, cols, :, 0]
print(ext)
```

**Output**

```
[[1.]
 [2.]
 [2.]
 [3.]
 [3.]
 [3.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do:

```
arr[lw_up_pair][:, 0]

array([[1.],
       [2.],
       [2.],
       [3.],
       [3.],
       [3.]])
```

Comment: Clever. The potential disadvantage is that you can't assign to this expression though.

Comment: you could always just assign to `arr[lw_up_pair]`, since the rest is just to get the number of dimensions correct, and you're pretty sure to get the broadcasting right.

Answer (score 2):

Since we are iteratively improving the indexing expressions:

```
arr[(*np.tril_indices(4, -1), slice(None), 0)]
```